# How can I add demand rate to Or-Tools vrp

Tags: .net, or-tools

Hı,I use a combination of these two examples.

[or-toolsvrptw](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw)

[or-tools cvtp](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp)

In the first and second in this case ( time_window), the amount requested by the dealer is different.
Can I give "demands" value range for this?

**I'm trying to optimize demands  in given demand intervals .  Optimization
should minimize routes in accordance with optimal demands .**

I want the first code to be like the second one.

First:

```
data['time_windows'] = [
  (0, 5),  # depot
  (7, 12),  # 1
  (10, 15),  # 2
  (16, 18),  # 3
  (10, 13),  # 4
  (0, 5),  # 5
  (5, 10),  # 6
  (0, 4),  # 7
  (5, 10),  # 8
  (0, 3),  # 9
  (10, 16),  # 10
  (10, 15),  # 11
  (0, 5),  # 12
  (5, 10),  # 13
  (7, 8),  # 14
  (10, 15),  # 15
  (11, 15),  # 16]

data['demands'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 8, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8]
```

Second:

```
data['demands'] = [(0,0), (1,3), (1,4), (1,3), (5,8), (2,4), (5,6), (6,6), (5,5), (1,4), (1,2), (3,4), (2,4), (1,3), (2,4),(1,3), (5,6)]

data['time_windows'] = [
  (0, 5),  # depot
  (7, 12),  # 1
  (10, 15),  # 2
  (16, 18),  # 3
  (10, 13),  # 4
  (0, 5),  # 5
  (5, 10),  # 6
  (0, 4),  # 7
  (5, 10),  # 8
  (0, 3),  # 9
  (10, 16),  # 10
  (10, 15),  # 11
  (0, 5),  # 12
  (5, 10),  # 13
  (7, 8),  # 14
  (10, 15),  # 15
  (11, 15),  # 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use one disjunction for each node whose the penalty is the value * coeff.
So the solver will have incentive to keep/visit node with high values...

see https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties